# Change of file in subfolder doesn't invalidate cache (ADD or COPY)

Tags: docker, shiny, docker-compose, dockerfile

While trying to dockerise an r-shiny app I am having problems with Docker cache invalidation. Changing a file in `/app` seems to invaildate cache only on `docker-compose build`  output, this doesn't reflect inside the container where files are not changed at all. Below the output of the build command:

```
Building app
Step 1/13 : FROM rocker/shiny:latestBuilding app
Step 1/13 : FROM rocker/shiny:latest
 ---> f184f6aaa052
Step 2/13 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get install libssl-dev -y     nano     libxml2-dev     libsodium-dev     libmariadbclient-dev     libhiredis-dev
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 03a28c35ec29
Step 3/13 : COPY install_packages.R  /tmp/install_packages.R
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f0f98562976d
Step 4/13 : RUN Rscript /tmp/install_packages.R
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1f66021a00f5
Step 5/13 : RUN R -e "install.packages('devtools', dependencies = TRUE, repos = 'http://cran.rstudio.com/')"
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c65054a0b033
Step 6/13 : RUN R -e "devtools::install_github('PaulC91/shinyauthr', dependencies = TRUE)"
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 29135386a24f
Step 7/13 : ARG CACHEPOP=1
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 2916da43a88f
Step 8/13 : ADD shiny-server.conf /etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f1289d6aba53
Step 9/13 : ADD shiny-server.sh /usr/bin/shiny-server.sh
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 87f462480ada
Step 10/13 : COPY app /srv/shiny-server/app
 ---> d89ae8e7fa85
Step 11/13 : RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/usr/bin/shiny-server.sh"]
 ---> Running in 27c53685d6ad
Removing intermediate container 27c53685d6ad
 ---> 6cb6baf130af
Step 12/13 : EXPOSE 3838
 ---> Running in 4425302562bb
Removing intermediate container 4425302562bb
 ---> e6c4fc565195
Step 13/13 : CMD ["usr/bin/shiny-server.sh"]
 ---> Running in 7723d0219648
Removing intermediate container 7723d0219648
 ---> 742d77a0a30e
Successfully built 742d77a0a30e
Successfully tagged redis-test:latest

 ---> f184f6aaa052
Step 2/13 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get install libssl-dev -y     nano     libxml2-dev     libsodium-dev     libmariadbclient-dev     libhiredis-dev
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 03a28c35ec29
Step 3/13 : COPY install_packages.R  /tmp/install_packages.R
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f0f98562976d
Step 4/13 : RUN Rscript /tmp/install_packages.R
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1f66021a00f5
Step 5/13 : RUN R -e "install.packages('devtools', dependencies = TRUE, repos = 'http://cran.rstudio.com/')"
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c65054a0b033
Step 6/13 : RUN R -e "devtools::install_github('PaulC91/shinyauthr', dependencies = TRUE)"
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 29135386a24f
Step 7/13 : ARG CACHEPOP=1
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 2916da43a88f
Step 8/13 : ADD shiny-server.conf /etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f1289d6aba53
Step 9/13 : ADD shiny-server.sh /usr/bin/shiny-server.sh
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 87f462480ada
Step 10/13 : COPY app /srv/shiny-server/app
 ---> d89ae8e7fa85
Step 11/13 : RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/usr/bin/shiny-server.sh"]
 ---> Running in 27c53685d6ad
Removing intermediate container 27c53685d6ad
 ---> 6cb6baf130af
Step 12/13 : EXPOSE 3838
 ---> Running in 4425302562bb
Removing intermediate container 4425302562bbBuilding app
Step 1/13 : FROM rocker/shiny:latest
 ---> f184f6aaa052
Step 2/13 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get install libssl-dev -y     nano     libxml2-dev     libsodium-dev     libmariadbclient-dev     libhiredis-dev
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 03a28c35ec29
Step 3/13 : COPY install_packages.R  /tmp/install_packages.R
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f0f98562976d
Step 4/13 : RUN Rscript /tmp/install_packages.R
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1f66021a00f5
Step 5/13 : RUN R -e "install.packages('devtools', dependencies = TRUE, repos = 'http://cran.rstudio.com/')"
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c65054a0b033
Step 6/13 : RUN R -e "devtools::install_github('PaulC91/shinyauthr', dependencies = TRUE)"
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 29135386a24f
Step 7/13 : ARG CACHEPOP=1
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 2916da43a88f
Step 8/13 : ADD shiny-server.conf /etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f1289d6aba53
Step 9/13 : ADD shiny-server.sh /usr/bin/shiny-server.sh
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 87f462480ada
Step 10/13 : COPY app /srv/shiny-server/app
 ---> d89ae8e7fa85
Step 11/13 : RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/usr/bin/shiny-server.sh"]
 ---> Running in 27c53685d6ad
Removing intermediate container 27c53685d6ad
 ---> 6cb6baf130afBuilding app
Step 1/13 : FROM rocker/shiny:latest
 ---> f184f6aaa052
Step 2/13 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get install libssl-dev -y     nano     libxml2-dev     libsodium-dev     libmariadbclient-dev     libhiredis-dev
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 03a28c35ec29
Step 3/13 : COPY install_packages.R  /tmp/install_packages.R
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f0f98562976d
Step 4/13 : RUN Rscript /tmp/install_packages.R
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1f66021a00f5
Step 5/13 : RUN R -e "install.packages('devtools', dependencies = TRUE, repos = 'http://cran.rstudio.com/')"
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c65054a0b033
Step 6/13 : RUN R -e "devtools::install_github('PaulC91/shinyauthr', dependencies = TRUE)"
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 29135386a24f
Step 7/13 : ARG CACHEPOP=1
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 2916da43a88f
Step 8/13 : ADD shiny-server.conf /etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f1289d6aba53
Step 9/13 : ADD shiny-server.sh /usr/bin/shiny-server.sh
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 87f462480ada
Step 10/13 : COPY app /srv/shiny-server/app
 ---> d89ae8e7fa85
Step 11/13 : RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/usr/bin/shiny-server.sh"]
 ---> Running in 27c53685d6ad
Removing intermediate container 27c53685d6ad
 ---> 6cb6baf130af
Step 12/13 : EXPOSE 3838
 ---> Running in 4425302562bb
Removing intermediate container 4425302562bb
 ---> e6c4fc565195
Step 13/13 : CMD ["usr/bin/shiny-server.sh"]
 ---> Running in 7723d0219648
Removing intermediate container 7723d0219648
 ---> 742d77a0a30e
Successfully built 742d77a0a30e
Successfully tagged redis-test:latest

Step 12/13 : EXPOSE 3838
 ---> Running in 4425302562bb
Removing intermediate container 4425302562bb
 ---> e6c4fc565195
Step 13/13 : CMD ["usr/bin/shiny-server.sh"]
 ---> Running in 7723d0219648
Removing intermediate container 7723d0219648
 ---> 742d77a0a30e
Successfully built 742d77a0a30e
Successfully tagged redis-test:latest

 ---> e6c4fc565195
Step 13/13 : CMD ["usr/bin/shiny-server.sh"]
 ---> Running in 7723d0219648
Removing intermediate container 7723d0219648
 ---> 742d77a0a30e
Successfully built 742d77a0a30e
Successfully tagged redis-test:latest
```

As you can see, cache is indeed invalidated in step **10/13**, but this is not reflected inside the container, where I still see the old file (with no new files being added). `ADD` and `COPY` yield the same behaviour.

Is this normal behaviour or is there anything I am not seeing?

Folder structure and Dockerfile, for thoroughness' sake:

```
.
├── app
│   ├── global.R
│   ├── mock_users.R
│   ├── server.R
│   ├── test.txt
│   └── ui.R
├── docker-compose.yml
├── Dockerfile
├── install_packages.R
├── readme.md
├── redis_cache_test.Rproj
├── shiny-server.conf
└── shiny-server.sh
```

```
FROM rocker/shiny:latest

# install openssl
# libsodium for shinyauthr
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install libssl-dev -y \
    nano \
    libxml2-dev \
    libsodium-dev \
    libmariadbclient-dev \
    libhiredis-dev

# install packages and remove downloaded files
COPY install_packages.R  /tmp/install_packages.R
RUN Rscript /tmp/install_packages.R

# install shiny authr package
RUN R -e "install.packages('devtools', dependencies = TRUE, repos = 'http://cran.rstudio.com/')"
RUN R -e "devtools::install_github('PaulC91/shinyauthr', dependencies = TRUE)"

# copy config files
ARG CACHEPOP=1
ADD shiny-server.conf /etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf
ADD shiny-server.sh /usr/bin/shiny-server.sh

# copy app
COPY app /srv/shiny-server/app

## allow permissions
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/usr/bin/shiny-server.sh"]

# expose port
EXPOSE 3838

CMD ["usr/bin/shiny-server.sh"]
```

Comment: Did you remove and create a new container? Do you have any volumes defined?

Comment: Yes, I have defined a volume that maps `/app:/srv/shiny-server` in the docker-compose file

Comment: in that case, you will only see the volume contents and not the image contents. Rebuilding the image would make no difference.

Comment: Makes sense @BMitch, forgive my ignorance. Mind writing a really brief answer so we can close it properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your build output, as you've observed, the cache is indeed invalidated and you build a new image with the new contents of your directory. However, from the comments, you then run this container with a volume `/app:/srv/shiny-server` which will map access to this directory inside the container in `/srv/shiny-server` to the host at `/app`. Note that this path is an absolute path, rather than a relative path, so the files are on the host at `/app` rather than in your build directory in `./app`.

Depending on your use case, there are various solutions. First, in the compose file, you have access to relative paths, so if you are testing locally (the typical reason to mount a volume), then you often want to mount the volume with a relative path like `./app:/srv/shiny-server`. The result is the container runs with the contents of this directory without needing to rebuild the image, which is often preferred for faster development cycles.

If you do not want the volume mount, e.g. if this is in production and there's no need to access the files from outside of the container, then removing the volume mount from the compose file is preferred.

And lastly, if you need to have external access to these files, but you want them to be updated by the contents of your image, then you typically want to save the contents of the volume somewhere safe and update the volume with an entrypoint script. In my [docker-base repo](https://github.com/sudo-bmitch/docker-base), I do this with the `save-volume` and `load-volume` scripts, one to run during the image build, and the other for during the entrypoint when running the container.

Comment: All sorted now, thanks a lot for the thorough answer.